# CSS classes 'doubled up' when manipulated in JS

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to add arrows to my sortable columns in my table.

The first time around it works fine, then it doubles up the classes.

headerUnSort -> headerSortDown -> headerSortUp -> headerUnSort headerSortDown

Anyone know why this is happening? (I also have to remove a 'header' class for some aggravating reason.)

```
$(this).removeClass('header');

if (this.className == 'headerUnSort')
{
    $(this).removeClass();
    this.className = 'headerSortDown';
}
else if (this.className == 'headerSortDown')
{
    $(this).removeClass();
    this.className = 'headerSortUp';
}
else if (this.className == 'headerSortUp')
{
    $(this).removeClass();
    this.className = 'headerUnSort';
}
```

Comment: Element.className is a string of all calsses, so it could be 'class1 class2'. The comparison should then be for 'has this class' (see [$.hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)), not 'has *only* this class'. Then use removeClass for *just that* class for clarity and accidental 'whoops' later when a class was meant to be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without more context, but I don't think that code is doing exactly what you think it's doing. Try this:

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.removeClass('header');

if ($this.hasClass('headerUnSort')) {
    $this.removeClass('headerUnSort');
    $this.addClass('headerSortDown');

} else if ($this.hasClass('headerSortDown')) {
    $this.removeClass('headerSortDown');
    $this.addClass('headerSortUp');

} else if ($this.hasClass('headerSortUp')) {
    $this.removeClass('headerSortUp');
    $this.addClass('headerUnSort');
}
```

or, this, which should be much faster:

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.removeClass('header');

if ($this.hasClass('headerUnSort')) {
    this.className = 'headerSortDown';

} else if ($this.hasClass('headerSortDown')) {
    this.className = 'headerSortUp';

} else if ($this.hasClass('headerSortUp')) {
    this.className = 'headerUnSort';
}
```

Comment: "Much faster" .. nope. No noticeable performance difference. I can click at ~8cps.

Comment: Well, no, it won't be a noticeable difference to the user. But it is computationally far less complex and will run faster if you put it to a performance test.

Comment: So .. "much faster" .. nope/irrelevant. Since using any jQuery, might as well use it entirely. I *would* capture $(this) as a local variable though, but with a different name, for clarity.

Comment: I found the issue in a table sorter I downloaded.  For whatever reason It was messing with my classes!  Thanks for the help.